# Android dictionary app design

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to create an Android dictionary-like application and get slow performance on retrieving the data. Currently, each dictionary entry is stored in a text file (inside Android assets), each file is named as number, so that I can use index to locate, open and read the file's content (simply read out a single line of String). When using `ListView` to render the output data and reading the file's content inside `getView()` method, it takes about 3 second to retrieve 10 entries. I just wonder if there are another approaches (using `SQLLite`, ???) for retrieving and rendering these entries faster. Any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: 3s for 10 entries seems slow, even for file-access. But of course, DO use sqlite!

Comment: Hi All, I changed to use SQLite and the load speed is much better now. The overhead of opening and reading files were too much. Thank All for your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `SQLite`

### Advantages

1. You can query
2. You can update definitions easily
3. Your data is more secure while using database (If you can `Encrypt`
   using `AES` or similar algorithm it, then it will become more
   secure!)
4. Fetching results is more faster
5. You can easily populate the results to a `ListView`

You can see a complete article [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

`SQLite` will definitely make your job easier and make the app work faster. It's also a lot easier to read data; when you're writing data to the DB make sure to use transactions to speed up multiple sequential writes. I probably wouldn't even consider using a text file except for initial data. There are many resources available online such as [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/).